# YouTube API - find channels with names containing spaces

Tags: json, api, youtube, youtube-channels

I'm using the YouTube API to show information about different YouTube channels.
I want to find YouTube users by username search, here's the link to the API.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list

When looking up channels like PewDiePie everything works.
My problem is with YouTube names with a space in the middle. When I for example look up "David Dobrik", I get no search results. Anyone knows how I get the info about channels with space-names?

I know you can find the channels with their YouTube channel ID, but that's not what I want.

What I get when looking up channels with spaces:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
 "etag": "\"Dn5xIderbhAnUk5TAW0qkFFir0M/fuSRoUc6R_qYNmJ5jD-Izxd1Nsc\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 0,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": []
}
```

Comment: I've search about this and it seems there's no solution for this one, you have to work with `channel_id` or consider post your issue on [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803). Check first if someone else has already posted a issue similar to yours. For more infor about issue tracker, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63960647/4092887).