# Possible bug when adding a newly created video to a playlist

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

As of recently, a script has been reporting failures when trying to add a newly created youtube video to a playlist.

The flow is pretty simple:

```
URL being requested: POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?uploadType=resumable&alt=json&part=status%2Csnippet
Video id 'ABC123' was successfully uploaded.
Adding ABC123 to playlist MyPlaylistId
URL being requested: POST https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?alt=json&part=snippet
Payload:
{"snippet": {"resourceId": {"kind": "youtube#video", "videoId": "ABC123"}, "playlistId": "MyPlaylistId"}}
Response:
{'status': '404', 'content-length': '226', 'x-xss-protection': '0', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer', 'server': 'scaffolding on HTTPServer2', '-content-encoding': 'gzip', 'cache-control': 'private', 'date': 'Thu, 17 Sep 2020 12:13:36 GMT', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'alt-svc': 'h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-27=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}
Response content:
{
 "error": {
   "code": 404,
   "message": "Video not found.",
   "errors": [
     {
       "message": "Video not found.",
       "domain": "youtube.playlistItem",
       "reason": "videoNotFound"
     }
   ]
  }
}
```

Now, the funny part is that the video is actually **successfully added** to the playlist. I have tested it several times and I get the same result.

Can anyone confirm this bug?

Comment: Note: I have reported this bug here as this seems to be the official support site for the google apis as stated here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems indeed a bug, but, as far as I know, the site for post about bugs with the YouTube APIs is: [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues)<sup>1</sup>.

The following [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803) allows you create an entry on Issue Tracker.

It is worth check first if entries exists with the similar issue you're facing and if you find related entries there, please "star" that issue to draw attention to it and track updates, if you'd like.

---

<sup>1</sup> Issue Tracker is shown (*alongside Stack Overflow*) at the end of the page of [YouTube Data API website](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3).

Comment: Indeed, seems that I have misses that link at the footer. Thanks!