# iFrame embed (for Youtube video) not appearing in Safari

Tags: wordpress, video, iframe, safari, youtube

My Youtube embed appears in Chrome and Firefox, but it doesn't appear in Safari (which includes mobile Safari on the iPhone). I get the same result using Vimeo or native HTML5 video - nothing appears in this div. Here's a 1-minute video that shows exactly what's happening:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnqDlmYOKW8

I tried `z-index`, `position`, changing the `width` and `height` of the iFrame, changing `https` to `http`, removing `encrypted-media` in the embed code, and so much more.

The website is https://waltrib.com/shop/ and the test product is "Heavy Dirt". I'm using a plugin called Booster Wordpress that allows me to change product images into custom HTML (so I'm using it for Youtube embeds).

At 0:48 in the video above - what's bizarre is that when I open the Developer Inspector and add anything like `www` then the iFrame appears. Weird. When browsing in Safari, it renders Youtube embeds on every single page of the website, except for the /shop page.

I read [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34494102/youtube-embed-video-not-working-with-safari) which suggests using `object` but that didn't work.

Has anything seen a bug like this? It's one of the strangest things I've seen recently.

Comment: If is a bug, then, search if a ticked was posted on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues) or post a ticket there - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63960647/12511801) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of :

```
src="https://youtube.com/embed/5i9SzaumaRg"
```

Use:

```
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5i9SzaumaRg" // Note the "www"
```

Sounds silly, but works.

Update:
It seems a change in URL of any kind refreshes the iframe and hence it appears so following would work:

```js
let i = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
i.setAttribute("src",i.getAttribute("src")+"?r=4535");
```

Execute this code only after iframe is loaded. Use load handler for that.

Comment: I tried that at 0:48 in the video but it doesn't work. I also mentioned that in the 4th paragraph. I also tried "Safari > Preferences > Privacy and uncheck Prevent cross-site tracking" which does nothing.

Well, when I type "www" into the inspector it works, but it doesn't work when loading the page. I know we're close though. It's a bizarre bug.

Comment: One thing I noticed is that if I add "www" to the embed, and then open up the Developer Inspector to delete the "www" then it appears. So the embed appears anytime there's an edit to the webpage using the Developer Inspector. I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding parameters to iFrame src link:

```
<iframe src="https://youtube.com/embed/5i9SzaumaRg?enablejsapi=1&origin=https://example.com/" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```

More on my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75511731/21251815).